# Text over image css (slightly different)

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

using Visual studio 2012, Umbraco 7 c# .net 4 css3  boostrap.

ok so i have gone over all the standard "text over image" stuff and it wall works in js fiddle etc, however my situation is very slightly different.

css:

```
.project-tile{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.project-tile:after{
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #26C1E3;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
.project-tile:hover:after{
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.text-left-overlay{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;   
}
```

heres the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 testborder col-nopad ">
        <div class="project-tile">
            <img class="img-responsive project-image" src="../media/temp/18Pedruscot-2-1280x480.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="text-left-overlay">Title Text</p>
        </div>           
    </div>
```

So i already have a hover effect that shows a blue opacity background on top of the image.

Because of how this is done the text overlay isnt really working.

I need the text to appear when hovered on top of the image and overlay, later i will add my own transitions etc but that isnt important right now.

Whats the tweak i need to do to achieve this?

If you have trouble understanding my question please let me know and ill try to provide more info

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10170/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yr1x7uwu/

I've moved the title text before the image in the HTML, because it wasn't overlaying it, and added hover state to `text-left-overlay`.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.project-tile{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.project-tile:after{
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #26C1E3;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
.project-tile:hover:after{
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.project-tile:hover .text-left-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text-left-overlay{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 testborder col-nopad ">
            <div class="project-tile">
                <p class="text-left-overlay">Title Text</p>
                <img class="img-responsive project-image" src="http://s9.postimg.org/54ngc5yvz/18_Pedruscot_2_1280x480.jpg" alt="" />
              
            </div>           
        </div>
```

Is that what you were trying to achieve?